# Swift Realm [[String]] object

Tags: arrays, swift3, realm

I'm new to Realm and have been through the documentation a few times. I need to persist a [[String]] and have not found a way to do it yet

```
 var tableViewArray = [[String]]()
```

I see the documentation pointing to Lists but I've been unsuccessful at implementing them. I'm showing my whole process here but just need help persisting my var `tableViewArray = [[String]]()`in Realm

This is my class

```
class TableViewArrays {

var tableViewArray = [[String]]()  // populates the Main Tableview

/// add picker selection to tableview array
func appendTableViewArray(title: String, detail: String, icon: String ) {

        var newRow = [String]()
        newRow.append(title)
        newRow.append(detail)
        newRow.append(icon)
        tableViewArray.append(newRow)
}
```

In the View Controller I instantiate the object

```
var tableViewArrays = TableViewArrays()
```

Then call the class function to populate the object

```
var tableViewArrays.appendTableViewArray(title: String, detail: String, icon: String )
```

Thank you for taking a look

Comment: Can you post the code where the Realm object you're persisting is declared?

Comment: I believe I have a solution for this. Here are the objects:

Comment: ˚Sorry -- have trouble adding code blocks --   class TableViewRow: Object {
    dynamic var icon = ""
    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var detail =  ""
    
    override var description: String { return "TableViewRow {\(icon), \(title), \(detail)}" }
}
class EventTableView: Object {
    let rows = List<TableViewRow>()
    //override var description: String { return "Car {\(brand), \(name), \(year)}" }
}

Answer (score 2):

I would make two Realm objects to be persisted, then nest them. Here's an example:

```
class RealmString: Object {
    dynamic var value = ""
}

class RealmStringArray: Object {
    let strings = List<RealmString>()
}

class TableViewArray{
    let stringArrays = List<RealmStringArray>()
}
```

I can't say much about the efficiency of this method, but I suppose it should work for your purpose. Also, if you have a large amount of data, it may become a pain to persist each individual string, then string collection, the string collection collection.

Comment: Thanks Faris, nice solution and I appreciate the help!

Comment: This is the recommended way to do it for now. Storing arrays of primitives is on the roadmap for Realm (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1120), so hopefully this will be a better experience in future. :)

Comment: Feel free to mark a solution you're satisfied with as correct! @user6530825

Answer (score 1):

create the classes

```
class TableViewRow: Object {
    dynamic var icon = ""
    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var detail =  ""

    override var description: String { 
    return "TableViewRow {\(icon), \(title), \(detail)}" }
}

class EventTableView: Object {
    let rows = List<TableViewRow>()
}
```

then instantiate the objects and append

```
let defaultTableview = EventTableView()
let rowOne = TableViewRow()

rowOne.icon = "man icon" ; rowOne.title = "War Hans D.O.P." ; rowOne.detail = "Camera Order Nike 2/11/17"

defaultTableview.rows.append(objectsIn: [rowOne])
```